# DynamoDB docClient scan does not respond

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-nodejs

I use DynamoDB with nodeJS on a Lambda function using serverless.
When I scan item from my local computer it works but when I deploy my function scan does not respond. No errors

```js
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
});

const checkApiKey = async (apiKey, ) => {
  try {
    log.debug("before scan");
    let result = await docClient
      .scan({
        "MY_TABLE",
        FilterExpression: "#apiKey = :apiKey",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#apiKey": "apiKey",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":apiKey": apiKey },
      })
      .promise();
     log.debug("after scan");
  } catch (error) {
    log.error("Can not get dynamo object", { message: error.message });
    throwError(error);
  }
};
```

When I call this function on AWS, I can see in my log `before scan` but I don't see `after scan` nor error message from catch.

DynamoDB operations like "create" works fine.

I have been looking for a solution for several days ... Without success

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's causing your problem, but the first thing that stuck out to me is how you are defining the table name in the call to scan:

```
 .scan({
        "MY_TABLE",
        ...
```

According to the docs, that should be a key/value pair

```
 .scan({
        TableName: "MY_TABLE",
        ...
```

If you are using the Serverless Framework, do you get different results if you run the function local vs remote?

For example, running the function locally from the command line:

```
sls invoke local --function <FUNCATION NAME from serverless.yml>
```

vs running the function remotely (in AWS) from the command line

```
sls invoke --function <FUNCATION NAME from serverless.yml>
```

Comment: You are right, it is an extract of my code and I have changer TableName to post my question. I use correctly TableName:"MY_TABLE"

Comment: I tried to call locally my function and it works fine;  scan returned a result. But when I try remotly, no result is returned from scan

Comment: How are you defining the region?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the callbacks for the promise of `await docClient.scan().promise()`

I mean:

```js
let result = await docClient
    .scan({
        TableName: "MY_TABLE",
        FilterExpression: "#apiKey = :apiKey",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#apiKey": "apiKey",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":apiKey": apiKey },
    })
    .promise()
    .then(data => console.log)
    .catch(error => console.error)
```

and check the result, maybe then the picture became clear.

Comment: I already use await and catch to wait for promise result; I can't use both method 
 : await and then

Comment: BTW: scan is quite an expensive operation, is it also possible that you are not waiting until the scan has been finished? How much data is in DynamoDB table?

Comment: only 1 record :) it is the first AWS deployment of this component !

Comment: try also to define the region where the DynamoDB is located: 

const dynamoClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
})

Comment: I already set the region. I have also added dynamodb endpoint

Comment: Do other commands work for you except scan? I mean `docClient.get`,`docClient.put`, `docClient.query` etc.